# What vocal techniques are used to sing and talk like a girl?

Tags: voice

I'm wondering what techniques or training these people went through or use to do these types of voices?

Here's the girl voice at 0:40 (it's a guy)

then here's a guy singing a duet.

Are they using falsetto and reinforced falsetto?

I'm really interested in this voice here. I'm surprised it's a guy. What techniques does it sound like he is using? Is it a MIX, or is it pure reinforced falsetto, or other? How is he making his formants sound so much like a female? and intonation?

here is another amazing singer, what techniques is he using?

Answer (score 9):

I could only tolerate about 15 seconds of the top (first) audio before I clicked it off.

That 'girl' voice was achieved by recording the male voice at a lower pitch or speed, and then speeding up the tape or digital signal to a higher pitch. (Picture Alvin and the Chipmunks and you get the idea.)

As far as the bottom video, if authentic, that young man has an incredible vocal range. Very little of his 'girl' singing voice utilized falsetto, and the parts that were falsetto were smooth and unforced.

Fantastic voice on that fellow!

The reality is that most males would be unable to simulate a young female voice, not without a horrible, forced falsetto, much like the characters on the Monty Python's Flying Circus skits employed.

It takes natural gifts and a very high singing voice to pull that off. No technique necessarily.

Comment: I did some info-gathering. The guy is genuine, winner of 'Philipinas Got Talent' in 2011. [Wikipedia - Marcelito Pomoy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcelito_Pomoy) Lots of live footage on YouTube, though the radio broadcast above is about the most listenable.

Comment: Thank you for that! I will do some more research. I want to hear more of that guy, for sure. What a voice!

Answer (score 1):

look for instructions for transwomen. if you spend a very long time practicing you don't have to use much technique to get a perfect girl voice

for instance, you'll learn to focus less on your voice's pitch & more on whether the sound feels like it's coming from your head or throat or chest